# Unable to login into ubuntu(16.04) after CUDA installation

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, cuda

I was trying to train the classifier using OpenFace framework. As part of the installation process, I executed the following commands for CUDA installation:

```
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local-ga2_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install cuda
```

After system restart I am unable to login.
Running a Ubuntu VM (Windows 10 host) and installed CUDA in Ubuntu. Do I need to install any Nvidia drivers in Ubuntu?

Comment: Upon the OS (windows 10) i installed ubuntu VM and installed CUDA in ubuntu. Do i need to install any nvidia drivers in ubuntu ?

Comment: CUDA doesn't work in a VM.

Comment: Is CUDA mandatory to train my classifier in GPU mode ?

Comment: No idea. If it is you'll have to run it in a proper installation with Nvidia drivers. In a VM you don't have access to the physical hardware, only to the virtualized hardware provided by whatever VM software you're using. No Nvidia hardware > No Nvidia drivers > No CUDA.

Answer (score 1):

Finally the issue is resolved.

1. once i got my logon screen. press ctrl-Alt-F1
2. `apt-get purge nvidia*`
3. `apt-get purge cuda*`
4. press ctrl-Alt-F7 (it will be redirected to login screen)

FYI:
Never install CUDA on Ubuntu VM